# Prestashop total price in order confirm

Tags: prestashop

I need help with prestashop header.tpl file. I need to get total order price. This value is needed for me to use in javascript file. I'm try to get price via using this:

```
{print_r($cart)}
---------
{print_r($order)}
---------
sdgsdg: {$total} --:{$order->total_paid}
{$cart->getOrderTotal(true)}

{{count($cart->getProducts())}}

{foreach $cart->getProducts() as $cacheproduct }
{{$cacheproduct['id_product']}};
{/foreach}
-----<br />
{$smarty.get.id_cart}<br />
-------231241---
{$_GET['id_cart']}<br />
-adsgasdg-asd-ha-sd-h
{$total_to_pay}
{$id_order_formatted}<br /> <br />
dddsadsdas
{print_r($order->getProduct)}
fasdfasdf
{$cart->getOrderTotal(true)}
```

but this does not work :/

What I'm need: In file header.tpl I must get total pay price.
for example:

```
{if $page_name == "order-confirmation"}
{code to get total price}
{/if}
```

Comment: When rendering the header, the $order might have not been set yet. You could override the order confirmation to set the values you need when rendering the header, or try to modify your implementation logic. I would go with the last option, if possible. What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with override

```
class Link extends LinkCore
{
    public function getPriceTotalByIdCart($idCart)
    {
    return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT total_paid_real FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders WHERE id_cart = '.(int)$idCart);
}

   public function getPriceTotalByIdOrder($idOrder)
   {
       return Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT total_paid_real FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders WHERE id_order = '.(int)$idOrder);
   }
}
```

And in header tpl with :

```
{$link->getPriceTotalByIdCart($smarty.get.id_cart}
```

OR

```
{$link->getPriceTotalByIdOrder($smarty.get.id_order}
```

Regards

Comment: It not works, on my shop I'm using "module"  guest-tracking and how in this module get the order information, like order id, all product id and total price ?

Comment: Try with : {$link->getPriceTotalByIdCart($cookie->id_cart)}